# pe:ckEditor does not fire change event on paste

Tags: primefaces, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

When I try to paste something to `pe:ckEditor`, it is not recognizing. My code is recognizing typed text but not pasted text. If I paste some text, the listener is also not getting invoked and `report.conclusion` value is `null`.

Simply, the pasted text is not being bound to `#{report.conclusion}`.

```html
<pe:ckEditor id="editor" width="100%" value="#{report.conclusion}"  
    toolbar="[['Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike'], ['TextColor'], ['Outdent', 'Indent'], ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList'], ['Center'], ['Table']]">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="btnSaveChanges" />
</pe:ckEditor>
```

Comment: It's working in the showcase https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/ckEditor/events.jsf. Please note that change is triggered on each key stroke. You might want to add a delay to the Ajax listener.